# python 3 print result of function giving error

Tags: python-3.x

I have researched this question thoroughly here:

- [Python 3 - Print Syntax Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40198188/python-3-print-syntax-error)
- [Python 3 print() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21127341/python-3-print-function)
- [python 3 print function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54546056/python-3-print-function)

and I have tried various layouts to try and get it to work.

```
print(merkle(txtHashes))
ha = merkle(txtHashes)
print(ha)
```

the code comes from here a Python 2.7 script see below:

```
import hashlib

# Hash pairs of items recursively until a single value is obtained
def merkle(hashList):
    if len(hashList) == 1:
        return hashList[0]
    newHashList = []
    # Process pairs. For odd length, the last is skipped
    for i in range(0, len(hashList)-1, 2):
        newHashList.append(hash2(hashList[i], hashList[i+1]))
    if len(hashList) % 2 == 1: # odd, hash last item twice
        newHashList.append(hash2(hashList[-1], hashList[-1]))
    return merkle(newHashList)

def hash2(a, b):
    # Reverse inputs before and after hashing
    # due to big-endian / little-endian nonsense
    a1 = a.decode('hex')[::-1]
    b1 = b.decode('hex')[::-1]
    h = hashlib.sha256(hashlib.sha256(a1+b1).digest()).digest()
    return h[::-1].encode('hex')

txtHashes = [
  "00baf6626abc2df808da36a518c69f09b0d2ed0a79421ccfde4f559d2e42128b",
  "91c5e9f288437262f218c60f986e8bc10fb35ab3b9f6de477ff0eb554da89dea",
  "46685c94b82b84fa05b6a0f36de6ff46475520113d5cb8c6fb060e043a0dbc5c"]

print merkle(txtHashes)
```

This works on Python 2.7, I can't get it to work on Python 3 even when I change the bottom line to

```
print(merkle(txtHashes))
```

Error given:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python30/MerkleRootTrial.py", line 126, in <module>
    print(merkle(txtHashes))
  File "C:/Python30/MerkleRootTrial.py", line 10, in merkle
    newHashList.append(hash2(hashList[i], hashList[i+1]))
  File "C:/Python30/MerkleRootTrial.py", line 18, in hash2
    a1 = a.decode('hex')[::-1]
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

Comment: The reason why the Error refers to a line 126 is because I shorted the list under txtHashes from 99 to 3 for neatness so the error is really about the end Print function

Comment: @benediktwerner your solution worked. Also to other's following my code was taken from Ken Shirriff's Blog on Merkle Root. His was written in Python 2.7. benediktwerner suggestions allows this to be now run on Python 3. Change the last line to print(merkle(txtHashes)) and the output will be correct with just a 'b' in front.

Answer (score 2):

In Python 3 `str` and `bytes` are different types while they were the same in Python 2. In Python 3 only `bytes`-objects have a `decode()` function and only `str`-objects have `encode()`, so you can't do `a.decode('hex')` because `a` is a `str`.

Also, some (I think all?) pseudo-encodings like `"hex"` (and a few others like `"zip"` and `"rot13"`) were removed, so you can't convert `strings` and `bytes` from/to hex anymore using `en/decode()`. Instead, you can use `binascii`:

```py
import binascii

binascii.hexlify(a) # instead of a.encode("hex")
binascii.unhexlify(a) # instead of a.decode("hex")
```

Note, that `hexlify()` only takes `bytes`-objects (which only makes sense) and both of those methods also return `bytes`-objects, but you can convert `str` to `bytes` and the other way around using `en/decode()`:

```py
b"abc".decode() -> "abc"
"abc".encode() -> b"abc"
```

In your case you need to `import binascii` change `hash2` to this:

```py
def hash2(a, b):
    # Reverse inputs before and after hashing
    # due to big-endian / little-endian nonsense
    a1 = binascii.unhexlify(a)[::-1]
    b1 = binascii.unhexlify(b)[::-1]
    h = hashlib.sha256(hashlib.sha256(a1+b1).digest()).digest()
    return binascii.hexlify(h[::-1]) # add .decode() here if you want str instead of bytes
```

Comment: You could also use the built-in `bytes.fromhex()` in place of `binascii.unhexlify()` and then `.hex()` in place of `binascii.hexlify()`

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know those methods existed. Yeah, that's probably cleaner.

Comment: @benediktwerner as the difference was so substantial and there was some urgency I have switched to another computer and installed Python 2.7 I hope to follow up on this when I get back to my Python3 computer and will post my trials with your suggestions.

Comment: See note above in my comments, your solution worked.

Answer (score 1):

To add to benediktwerner's answer, you can also decode the hex string to bytes using the following two methods in python 3.x:

```
import codecs
a1 = codecs.decode(a, 'hex_codec')[::-1]
```

Or, if you prefer not to import:

```
a1 = bytes.fromhex(a)[::-1]
```

From these two examples, the returned values for a1 are equal.